# Smiley support TextBox in windows phone winrt 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I need Textbox to display both image and text, like a RichTextBox in WPF, but in windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 we don't have that control, so any toolkit will support that.

```
<RichTextBox>
  <Paragraph>
    Content Text
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <Image Source="img.png" Height="50" Width="50" />
    </InlineUIContainer>            
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RichEditBox for your purpose.
This control supports image inserting, text formatting like underline, bold and much more.

Comment: could you please share the link that could be more usefull for me, or provide some sample code snippet.